# Split a string from a table into a new table

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008

I am aware from searching in advance of posting this question there are a number of threads realted to string splitting but I can't find one that covers exactly what I'm after.

I have table of data, one column of which is string seperated by comma's. What I am looking to do is to create a new table with all the origonal data and the strinf seperated out into individual columns for each value.

The inital table looks like this:

```
Value 1    Value 2    Value 3     Value 4  

abc        def        ghi         123,456,789

qrs        tuv        wxy         987,654,321
```

and I woould like the result to look like

```
Value 1    Value 2    Value 3     Value 4    Value 5    Value 6
abc        def        ghi         123        456        789
qrs        tuv        wxy         987        654        321
```

I'm working with SQL Server 2008, also in reality the string is longer and has 30 values in it so advice on how to scale the solution to that many values would be much apreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select Value  , Substring(Value4, 1,Charindex(',', FullName)-1) as Value5,
Substring(FullName, Charindex(',', Value4)+1, LEN(FullName)) as  Value6
from Table1
```

For more information [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)